# React Native Add Top thin header

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hello I'm developing a react native app everything is fine but I have a problem [image]

```
 return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>

      <View style={styles.container}>

          <StatusBar
            translucent={true}
            backgroundColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}
            barStyle={'light-content'}
          />
          { this.gradient }
          <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollview}
            scrollEventThrottle={200}
            directionalLockEnabled={true}
          >
              { carousel } 

              <FlatList
              data={ this.state.GridListItems }
              renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.GridViewContainer}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('ProfileScreen', { height: "6'2", category: item.key })}>
                <ImageBackground
                  source={{ uri: item.img }}
                  style={{width: '108%', height: '110%', justifyContent:'center'}}
                >
                <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}  > {item.key} </Text>
                </ImageBackground>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
            numColumns={2}
     />
          </ScrollView>

      </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

styles

```
    safeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.black
},
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.background1
},
```

when I scroll down you see the mobile battery and wifi (top bar) is in the app

I want the app to be below the mobile topbar how can I achieve that?
 here is an expo qr code 
[image]

Comment: Please show what style you are using in `styles.safeArea` and `styles.container` too.

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once try this and let me know your results:

```
     import React,{Fragment} from 'react';


            return (
              <Fragment>
               <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
               <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>

               <View style={styles.container}>

              { this.gradient }
              <ScrollView
                style={styles.scrollview}
                scrollEventThrottle={200}
                directionalLockEnabled={true}
              >
                  { carousel } 

                  <FlatList
                  data={ this.state.GridListItems }
                  renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.GridViewContainer}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('ProfileScreen', { height: "6'2", category: item.key })}>
                    <ImageBackground
                      source={{ uri: item.img }}
                      style={{width: '108%', height: '110%', justifyContent:'center'}}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}  > {item.key} </Text>
                    </ImageBackground>

                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                numColumns={2}
         />
              </ScrollView>

          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

i added safeareaview (flex:0) for statusBar you can apply any color you want.

provide options in your navigator file as:

```
navigationName: {
    screen: fileName,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        return {
          title: 'images',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#382464',
            height: 50,

          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          // header: props => <UriBar {...props} />
        }
      } else {
        return {
          header: null
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

you can also use statusBar for android

Comment: it worked on IOS but still the same on android any ideas ?

Comment: Perfect Thanks Man works just fine
does any of this affects Performance cuz my app is a bit slow

Comment: actually i also don't have idea about that. If you get proper answer do let me know

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`SafeAreaView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview).

It will render your component without overlapping the "top bar".

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'

...
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        // your components
    <SafeAreaView/>
)
```

## Edit:

As you can see in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview#usage-example).

> Simply wrap your top level view with a SafeAreaView with a flex: 1 style applied to it. You may also want to use a background color that matches your application's design.

So if you already using `SafeAreaView`, maybe you don't have `flex: 1` and it's not working in the way you want.

Comment: ty im using safe area view i updated the question :))
im using the navigation 3 can i enable the header but make it something like display none ?

Comment: @mohamedadel see my edit and also provide the styles you are using in `SafeAreaView`

Comment: @mohamedadel try removing `translucent={true}` and tell me what changes

Comment: Nothing chagned :D

Comment: @mohamedadel there is something weird here, you set the status bar background color to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` but it's fully transparent, try making it to `blue` and see if it becomes blue. or add a higher alpha, like  `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)`

Comment: i added blue but it's still transperant

Comment: @mohamedadel so something is changing it, try everything like it was normally but without `barStyle`. Maybe `barStyle` is changing all the other styles.

Comment: also tried without barstyle still nothing it''s really weird i really appretiate your help thanks man

Comment: @mohamedadel try othe mobile phone to see if that still happens

Comment: @mohamedadel sorry, i can't help more than that ;/